# .Net EF many-to-many with lookup table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a singular lookup table containing all static types/values combined under different categories. Initially, these types/values were stored in separate static tables.

However, we decided to merge them into one table. Here's an example of its structure:

```
ID | Name    | CATEGORY
---+---------+----------
1  | type 1  | book
2  | type 2  | book
3  | type 1  | Video
4  | type 2  | Video
5  | type 1  | Errors
6  | type 2  | Errors
7  | level 1 | Grade
8  | level 2 | Grade
9  | others  | other categories
```

Additionally, other business tables have many-to-many relationships with this lookup table based on their category.

For instance, the `Book` table may have a many-to-many relationship only with items under the `Book` category in the lookup table.

I'm using Entity Framework (EF), and I'm wondering what would be the better approach to set up this scenario.

Should I use one mapping table or have separate ones for each category (in terms of many-to-many relationships)?

And should I use `QueryFilter` to separate them into different entities?

Any suggestions or ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your EF models should be based on your table entities. If the above illustration is supposed to be a many-to-many junction table then Name and Category will be your two classes, which by the way are titled crappy. If you're looking to create entities based on field values then you should rethink this approach.